# PHP: 2nd while loop does not run?

Tags: php, loops

I have 2 while loops in my php code. The first one prints out the ingredients of a meal in a button / table format for display. The 2nd while loop puts the ingredients into a  list for selecting. However, when I run my code, only the first while loop runs successfully and the 2nd one does not.

I tried reversing the order, where the first while loop inputs the  list and the 2nd prints out the table to the screen. I got the options menu filled up, while the table did not print out, so I know that I didn't mess up in writing my options code.

What gives? Why can't I make 2 while loops in this code? I have seen other people do loops inside of loops, so i'm not sure why this code is failing to execute.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['view_meal'])){
        $meal = (string)$_POST['meal_names'];
        $meal_fk_q = "SELECT item
                      FROM meal_ingredients
                      WHERE meal_name='$meal'
                      ORDER BY item";
        $meal_fk_c = $conn->query($meal_fk_q);
        echo "<div class='view_meal_table_wrapper'>";
        while ($row = $meal_fk_c->fetch_assoc()){
             $view_ingredient = $row['item'];
             echo "<table class='view_meal_table'>
                      <tr>
                        <td class='view_meal cell'>$view_ingredient</td>
                      </tr>
                   </table>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<form action='createmeal.php' method='post'>
              <select name='remove_ingredients' placeholder='meals'>
              <option disabled selected value> -- Remove Ingredient -- </option>";

              while ($row = $meal_fk_c->fetch_assoc()){
                $view_ingredient = $row['item'];
                echo "<option>" . $view_ingredient . "</option>";
              }

        echo  "</select>
              <input type='submit' name='remove_ingredient' value='Remove Ingredient'>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your loops are not nested, they run sequentially. The first loop exhausts the results, so that none are left for the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in comments, first `while` loop receives **all** records from your db. That's why in the second `while` loop **nothing** is fetched. I advise you to join both loops into one:

```
echo "<div class='view_meal_table_wrapper'>";
$option_string = '';   // string with `options`
while ($row = $meal_fk_c->fetch_assoc()){
     $view_ingredient = $row['item'];
     echo "<table class='view_meal_table'>
              <tr>
                <td class='view_meal cell'>$view_ingredient</td>
              </tr>
           </table>";
     // add `option` markup to string
     $option_string .= "<option>" . $view_ingredient . "</option>";
}
echo "</div>";
echo "<form action='createmeal.php' method='post'>
      <select name='remove_ingredients' placeholder='meals'>
      <option disabled selected value> -- Remove Ingredient -- </option>";
echo $option_string;    // echo options here
echo  "</select>
      <input type='submit' name='remove_ingredient' value='Remove Ingredient'>";
```

Comment: Out of all the comments here, your answer was the most concise and simple to implement. I also tried your code / version and it worked. Thanks for the help and everyone else too.

Answer (score 0):

In first while the result set is completed traversing and there is no data left to traverse in second `while` loop.

Solution is to store result set and use it later in a `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['view_meal'])){
    $meal = (string)$_POST['meal_names'];
    $meal_fk_q = "SELECT item
            FROM meal_ingredients
            WHERE meal_name='$meal'
            ORDER BY item";
    $meal_fk_c = $conn->query($meal_fk_q);
    echo "<div class='view_meal_table_wrapper'>";

    $data = array();
    while ($row = $meal_fk_c->fetch_assoc()){
        $data = $row;
        $view_ingredient = $row['item'];
        echo "<table class='view_meal_table'>
            <tr>
            <td class='view_meal cell'>$view_ingredient</td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<form action='createmeal.php' method='post'>
        <select name='remove_ingredients' placeholder='meals'>
        <option disabled selected value> -- Remove Ingredient -- </option>";

        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            $view_ingredient = $row['item'];
            echo "<option>" . $view_ingredient . "</option>";
        }

    echo  "</select>
        <input type='submit' name='remove_ingredient' value='Remove Ingredient'>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The resource result you pass in to `$meal_fk_c->fetch_assoc()` is done by reference. You'll need to reset the position of the pointer before you can use `$meal_fk_c->fetch_assoc()` a second time.

To reset Position use:  `mysql_data_seek()`

OR Alternative

```
$arrayVals = array();
$result = mysql_query(/* Your query */);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arrayVals[] = $row;
}

// Now loop over the array twice instead

$len = count($arrayVals);
for($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++) {
    $row = $arrayVals[$x];

    // Do something here    
}

$len = count($arrayVals);
for($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++) {
    $row = $arrayVals[$x];

    // Do something else here   
}
```